# Can't list_options for capture card in ffmpeg : "Unable to BindToObject"

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video-capture, directshow

I'm trying to list the options of a "AJA Kona3G Quad" device on Windows 10 using ffmpeg.

> [dshow @ 000001343e7d9740] DirectShow video devices (some may be both
> video and audio devices) [dshow @ 000001343e7d9740]  "AJA S-Capture
> Kona3GQuad - 0"
>
> [dshow @ 000001343e7d9740]     Alternative name
> "@device_sw_{860BB310-5D01-11D0-BD3B-00A0C911CE86}{89BB1170-565C-49B6-9DED-D6D2DFCA06A8}"
>
> [dshow @ 000001343e7d9740] DirectShow audio
>
> [dshow @ 000001343e7d9740]  "AJA S-Capture [Audio] Kona3GQuad - 0"
>
> [dshow @ 000001343e7d9740]  Alternative name
> "@device_sw_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}{89BB1190-565C-49B6-9DED-D6D2DFCA06A8}"

Listing the devices seemsok, but once I get my device name and try to list it's options ffmpeg returns the following

> [dshow @ 000001aeac2a96c0] Unable to BindToObject for AJA S-Capture Kona3GQuad - 0
>
> [dshow @ 000001aeac2a96c0] Could not find video device with name [AJA
> S-Capture Kona3GQuad - 0] among source devices of type video.
>
> video=AJA S-Capture Kona3GQuad - 0: I/O error

Have any of you already encountered this issue, and if so could you point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptoms you mention indicate a problem in AJA Kona3G driver (actually, not even a driver *per se* but it's DirectShow integration implemented as a custom AJA DirectShow filter).

The system has this integration but it is either broken or out of date and so you see the DirectShow API issue coming from third party component and forwarded to FFmpeg.

You need to have AJA stuff re-installed and/or contact their support for a solution.